# Package web app for iOS - full screen iframe?

Tags: php, ios, ajax, web-applications, cordova

We have built an online web app and would now like to package it for ipad & iPhone. Ideally, all we need is a full screen browser window like an iframe that will load the full app from the web. Obviously we could do it in the browser but we need our own launch icon on the desktop as well as removal of the browser address bar. 
I've heard of phoneGap & Appcelerator but I'm unsure if this setup is possible using these platforms?

Is there a simple method for achieving this?

Are there any problems or security issues on iOS I need to look out for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of web application are on the app store. They just put a UIWebView in an empty app and point it to the web app. Everything will run just like it does in Safari, but there will be no toolbars, etc. This will require your to have Xcode and a membership to the developer program.

If you don't want to go through the app store, you can still set up your app so that you can save it to your device and it will run as though it were native. Here is a link with an example of that:

http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/

So you have to decide which is best for you.

**Native iOS app with UIWebView**

- Exposure on the app store
- Opens up the possibility to combine your app with native iOS UI elements if you want
- Possibility of using accelerometer, Bluetooth, Game Center, and other native app features

**"Offline" HTML5 App**

- No membership or Xcode required
- Full control of your app (no curation)
- Easily adaptable to work on other devices
- You don't have to pay a 30% cut if you sell something

In many cases, user experience will be identical for each option once the app is on the device. Weigh the options and figure out what's best for you.

**Directions for setting up native iOS app with UIWebView**

1. Open Xcode and select File > New > Project...
2. Enter a product name and select the device family. Check "Use Automatic Reference Counting" and uncheck "Use Storyboards" and "Include Unit Tests"
3. Pick where to put the project
4. Open ViewController.m and insert the code below in `viewDidLoad` right under above the line `[super viewDidLoad]`.
5. Change the url "http://www.google.com" to the address of your web app.

> ```
> UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
> NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
> NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
> [webView loadRequest:request];
> [self.view addSubview:webView];
> ```

Comment: Excellent thanks. It will eventually need to be in the app store and we need a normal installer so I guess UIWebView is the way to go. Do I need to know C for this or is there some framework I can use?

Comment: Just a few lines of Objective-C if any. I'll type up the steps and post them here if I can't find them anywhere else. Give me just a minute.

Comment: Sounds promising - Thanks woz. Is it possible to distribute the UIWebView or "offline" versions without the app store? In other words, Can I make it available for download (and automatic installation) from the web?

Comment: You can install apps with the offline HTML5 method from the web. They load right on to your device and, once installed, you can't tell the difference between it and a native app. If you update your HTML5 app, it's online, so the app will update automatically. It's the same as using UIWebView once it's on the device. Both will just get what's on your web server, so updates are immediate.

Comment: You could use the same web app and have it be available for installation from Safari and from the app store at the same time.

Comment: Great answer thanks again woz. One final question: When you say "You can install apps with the offline HTML5 method from the web." Do you mean they can pin the app to their desktop manually from safari or is it possible to simply download a file that runs an installation?

Comment: In Safari, you would touch the middle button (the box with the arrow) on the bottom toolbar and select "Add to Home Screen". That will put the app on your home screen the same way downloading it from the App Store would. When the user taps the icon, it won't take them back to Safari (as long as you set it up properly); it will just be your app that opens (no native toolbars, etc.). A lot of users don't know about that, but it will work if you follow the tutorial I linked to. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Ah ok - pity we cant do an automatic installer. Thanks again for the detailed info woz.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the user to add the website to their home screen, using something like [this](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen).

If they've done that, you can use 
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` to remove the standard Safari UI it won't display the standard Safari UI.

To specify an icon for the home screen, use `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png"/>`.

You can look for more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) about web apps on iOS, including how to set multiple icon sizes and how to set a launch image.

Comment: Cool, makes perfect sense - Thanks. Is there any way to package it up as an installer for the app store or otherwise?

Comment: The only way to have it in the App Store would be to obtain a developer license ($99) and submit it to the App Store. If you wanted to do this, it would be pretty simple – you'd only need to use a UIWebView that just displays the website. It could be done with only very limited knowledge of Objective-C.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good tutorial: http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/

Comment: Yeah, but Apple will reject your app if all it contains is a UIWebView of a website. An app needs to have more substance than that.

Comment: Will they? What's your source for that?

Comment: I updated my original post to include information on how to prompt the user to add the website to his.her home screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot adambinsz. I'd be very interested to see if Apple block a web app of this nature. Only one way to find out!

Comment: If you do decide to create an "app" for the website, make sure you handle errors in loading the website. If you don't, Apple will definitely reject your app.